# How can I use Flatten[list, 1] in this list?

Tags: list-manipulation

My code

```
list = Table[Expand[(k x - i)^2 -  j^2 y^2], {k, 2}, {i, 2}, {j, 2}];
Flatten[list, 1]
```

I get

> {{1 - 2 x + x^2 - y^2, 1 - 2 x + x^2 - 4 y^2}, {4 - 4 x + x^2 - y^2,
> 4 - 4 x + x^2 - 4 y^2}, {1 - 4 x + 4 x^2 - y^2,
> 1 - 4 x + 4 x^2 - 4 y^2}, {4 - 8 x + 4 x^2 - y^2,
> 4 - 8 x + 4 x^2 - 4 y^2}}

How can I get?

> {1 - 2 x + x^2 - y^2, 1 - 2 x + x^2 - 4 y^2, 4 - 4 x + x^2 - y^2,
> 4 - 4 x + x^2 - 4 y^2, 1 - 4 x + 4 x^2 - y^2,
> 1 - 4 x + 4 x^2 - 4 y^2, 4 - 8 x + 4 x^2 - y^2,
> 4 - 8 x + 4 x^2 - 4 y^2}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Flatten @ list
```

{1 - 2 x + x^2 - y^2, 1 - 2 x + x^2 - 4 y^2, 4 - 4 x + x^2 - y^2,
4 - 4 x + x^2 - 4 y^2, 1 - 4 x + 4 x^2 - y^2,
1 - 4 x + 4 x^2 - 4 y^2, 4 - 8 x + 4 x^2 - y^2,
4 - 8 x + 4 x^2 - 4 y^2}

Or, explicitly,

```
Flatten[list, Infinity]
```

(* same result *)

`Infinity` means: "Flatten **all** levels of `list`", which is the default, so you don't need to write it.